# Getting full url of any file in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to generate complete Url (with domain name etc) of any file in MVC. Example: A `.jpg` file or an `exe` file.

**Example: If I give "~/images/abc.jpg" it should return "http://www.mywebsite.com/images/abc.jpg"**

I am aware of the `Url.Action` overload that takes the protocol as a parameter. But `Url.Action` can be used only for Actions.

I want something like `Url.Content` function that takes protocol as a parameter.

Do you know if any method to get complete url of any file?

I have tried: `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute`, `ResolveClientUrl`, `ResolveUrl` but all of these don't seem to work.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the following code to replace "~/" to absoulute URL.

```
System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/")
```

**Edit:**

First you need to define a method.

```
public static string ResolveServerUrl(string serverUrl, bool forceHttps)
{
    if (serverUrl.IndexOf("://") > -1)
        return serverUrl;

    string newUrl = serverUrl;
    Uri originalUri = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
    newUrl = (forceHttps ? "https" : originalUri.Scheme) +
        "://" + originalUri.Authority + newUrl;
    return newUrl;
}
```

Now call this method will return the complete absolure url.

```
ResolveServerUrl(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/images/image1.gif"),false))
```

The output will be `http://www.yourdomainname.com/images/image1.gif`

Comment: The above code returns "/". That's it. Not the domain name with protocol like http:// www.mywebsite /

Comment: i have updated the answer. now it will fullfill the requirment

Comment: Adding strings is not the cleanest way. You should use built-in classes like Uri or UriBuilder.

Comment: Excellent. I combined your code with the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539156/how-to-generate-absolute-urls-with-https-in-mvc3 to provide an `@Url.Absolute` extension method. Thanks

Answer (score 59):

```
new Uri(Request.Url, Url.Content("~/images/image1.gif"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure which is the most efficient way, but I find this the easiest method to use and remember.

Comment: this should be the answer!! it is simple and done by default by NET so it is the best on flexibiity and maintainability

Comment: It's beautiful but it didn't work for me.. I still get something like `main/images/load.png` the domain is missing.

Comment: How would you use this in a view? I tried assigning it to a javascript variable and got a 500 error.

Comment: @RobertSmith You probably need to use `Uri.AbsoluteUri` to get a string.

Answer (score -5):

Try use this.

```
Url.Action("~/images/image1.gif", "/", null, Request.Url.Scheme)
```

Comment: OP talked about problems associated with this exact solution. The correct answer to this question was given 2 hours after the question was asked 3 years ago...

Comment: This one actually almost works but it puts in an extra path level if the image folder is at a higher level than the current view.