# Using Url.Content in a ASP.net MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using `Url.Content("~/something.jpg")` to get an absolute path in a view without problem.

I would like to use it in a controller but it doesn't work. It returns `"/something.jpg"` instead of "http://www.mydomain.com/something.jpg".

I tried several tricks found on google and stackoverflow without success.

Why `Url.Content()` doesn't work in a controller ?

Any idea will be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: the tilde `~` will point to the route of the site, so `URL.Content()` is doing what's expected.  Can you post the code you're using in the controller?

Comment: I only do that as the first instruction : String sUrlPublication = Url.Content("~/Publication/PublicationXML/"); and it returns : "/Publication/PublicationXML/" without the route of the site

Comment: @user3463579: What makes you think this is incorrect behavior?  If the application is in the root of the domain then `~` would resolve to `/`.

Comment: Because i get "http://www.mydomain.com/Publication/PublicationXML/" with exactly the same request from a view. I probably misunderstood something but Url.content() doesn't have the same behaviour between a view or a controller ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Generate absolute urls with https in MVC3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539156/how-to-generate-absolute-urls-with-https-in-mvc3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found what i'm looking for by using `new Uri(Request.Url, Url.Content("~/something.jpg"));`. It returns :

> http://www.mydomain.com/something.jpg;

Using only `Url.Content()` in a controller seems to be not enough. We have to use the `Uri` class to have the full URL.

Anyway, thank you everybody for your help

Comment: This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this is not working in controller probably because Url.Content is an mvc helper but I now how you can do what you want.If you want to get absolute path to your file you can try something like this:

```
var url=Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("../uploads"), "something.jpg");
```

In conclusion I think that  what you need is **Server.MapPath()**

Comment: It returns the path on my hard drive ("d:\something.jpg") and not what I'm looking for : the full URL ("www.mydomain.com/something.jpg").

Answer (score 0):

You could have a config entry that holds your URL, and append that to the front...

```
var sUrlPublication = ConfigHelper.SiteUrl + Url.Content("~/....");
```

Add the URL to `AppSettings`...

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SiteURL" value="...."/>
</appSettings>
```

You could add a `ConfigHelper` class...

```
using System.Configuration;

public static class ConfigHelper
{
  public static string SiteUrl
    {
      get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteURL"]; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Or as mentioned by Robert

```
var sUrlPublication = Request.Url.Host  + Url.Content("~/....");
```

Comment: or look at the Request object to find the domain the request is coming in on dynamically

Comment: @RobertLevy, as in using the `ServerVariables`?

Comment: No I mean just use Request.Url.Host