# Is there any reason not to use absolute paths in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, relative-path

All of the built-in framework methods in MVC, like `Url.Action` or `Url.Content` produce only relative urls in the resulting html. Lots of SO answers have provided ways to get the absolute path. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539156/how-to-generate-absolute-urls-with-https-in-mvc3):

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public static class UrlExtensions
{
    public static string Content(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string contentPath, bool toAbsolute = false)
    {
        var path = urlHelper.Content(contentPath);
        var url = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, path);

        return toAbsolute ? url.AbsoluteUri : path;
    }
}
```

works for me.

My question is, is there ever a reason not to use the absolute path? It is strictly better in terms of making your site more open to web scraping, accessibility tools, RSS feeds etc. Is there a down side? Seems like the absolute path should be default and the relative path should be the custom implementation.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of a web application where the page content is generated dynamically, it's perhaps less important that the URLs be relative. Traditionally, with static HTML, it would be a very bad idea to hardcode an absolute path. If you ever need to move the site, it would require finding every instance of the absolute URL and changing it.

However, it's still a best practice to only use as much of the URL as is necessary to route. While perhaps more rare, there are things like Google Cache, Archive.org, etc., where using the absolute path effectively breaks all ability to navigate within the cache. Short of this, though perhaps less common today, many proxies still exist out there that cache web pages view by users and then then dynamically route traffic to the cache rather than the actual website. Absolute URLs will break this as well.

Most of all, it's just unnecessary, and while it's minimal for sure, it does add additional weight to the page. For broadband users it's meaningless, but for someone using 3G metered data over an international connection, every byte counts.