# Get absolute path of file on content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there any easy (built in) way in an asp.net mvc view to get the absolute path of a file in the content folder?

At the moment I'm using

```
@Url.Content("~/Content/images/logo.png")
```

But the path returned isn't absolute.

I know it is possible to build its own helper for such cases but I'd like to know if there's any easier way...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1268755/802791

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Find Absolute Path to the App\_Data folder from Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268738/asp-net-mvc-find-absolute-path-to-the-app-data-folder-from-controller)

Comment: I have to check when the system is online as I use it for sending emails.
Will let you know tomorrow.
Thank you.

Comment: `Url.Content("~/...")` does return the absolute path.

Comment: try this helper. it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069922/getting-full-url-of-any-file-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: if I may make an observation -  you're not looking for an absolute path - this path is already returned by Url.Content. I guess you're looking for a Url containiing domain name, optionally port and the path to the image.

Answer (score 43):

This works for me:

A helper:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public static class UrlExtensions
{
    public static string Content(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string contentPath, bool toAbsolute = false)
    {
        var path = urlHelper.Content(contentPath);
        var url = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, path);

        return toAbsolute ? url.AbsoluteUri : path;
    }
}
```

Usage in cshtml:

```
@Url.Content("~/Scripts/flot/jquery.flot.menuBar.js", true)

// example output:
// http://example.com/directory/Scripts/flot/jquery.flot.menuBar.js
```

Comment: Note, that, `HttpContext.Current` does not exist in Core. Use `urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext`

Comment: I would suggest not making the last parameter defaulted/optional.  There is already a UrlHelper.Content instance method that takes a single string parameter.

Comment: To get this to work on ASP.NET Core 3.1, I the helper had to extend the interface: (`this IUrlHelper urlHelper`)

Answer (score 17):

This will generate an absolute url to an image (or file)

```
Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Url.Content("~/Content/images/logo.png")
```

This works in Asp.net Core

```
Context.Request.Scheme + "://" + Context.Request.Host + Url.Content("~/images/logo.png")
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been look for a good solution for the last hour. and yours works great.

Answer (score 6):

Url.Content does return the absolute path. What you want is the domain (and port). You can get the current domain by using:

```
Request.Url.Authority
```

Then combine this string with the absolute path string of your image.
It will return the domain name and if you are on a different port will also include the port number.

Comment: You also need to add the Scheme. Somethig like this: string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~/Content/images/logo.png"))

Answer (score 3):

```
new Uri(Request.Url, Url.Content("~/Content/images/logo.png"))
```

this calls the .ToString() of Uri. 
You can also put Uri in a variable and call .AbsoluteUri.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/logo.png");
```

Comment: The output of this one is:
C:\Users\...\Projects\...\Content\images\logo.png
What I really need is:
http://localhost:57001/Content/images/logo.png (in development environment)
and
http://www.mydomain.com/Content/images/logo.png (in productive environment)

Comment: @mosquito87 From the way your question was written, it wasn't really obvious what you want, so the answer was correct in relation to what you wrote (though not in relation to what you had in mind). As such I don't believe it deserved all the down votes that it got.

Comment: Dang, you got him there: He relied on the context of people reading the question knowing what web development was.