# Convert a string to URL in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying the following code to build an URL-

```
var httpPath= System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/ExcelFiles/" + fileName);
```

It returns -

```
/ExcelFiles/7b6ce1b2-828e-4c89-a893-bd32a00cd2e2.xlsx
```

But I want it to be -

```
http://my_site_address/ExcelFiles/7b6ce1b2-828e-4c89-a893-bd32a00cd2e2.xlsx
```

Any help?

Comment: Does this solves your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069922/getting-full-url-of-any-file-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: try this    var httpPath = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"))+"/ExcelFiles/" + fileName;